# SharePoint 2010 - URL Invalid. It may refer to a nonexistent file or folder

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am trying to upload documents to SharePoint 2010 site and i am getting the following error

The URL 'i74 Corridor/book/ADG Book_04-06-09.pdf' is invalid.  It may refer to a nonexistent file or folder, or refer to a valid file or folder that is not in the current Web

I found it could be the Database full and I cleared the log files of the Database but still i was facing the same issue. Could you please provide a solution to fix this issue.

Thanks,
Sandeep Manne

Comment: How are you trying to upload the file? Via the API or UI?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue and I have done few changes in DB settings as below.

1.Check the auto growth size of that DB

2.And see the Maximum file size limit increase it to around 2048 MB.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Sharepoit 2019, the solution for my issue was shrink WSS_Content database.